# Difference between ExecutorService and Volley

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm learning `Volley` as my network library to fetch data from the internet because `AsyncTask` is deprecated and I've come across `ExecutorService` that works like `Asynctask` so what's the difference between `Volley` and `ExecutorService`

Comment: Read about `Volley` and `ExecutorService` on the [Android API page](https://developer.android.com/reference). To replace `AsyncTask` you can use `Executor`;  `ExecutorService` is irrelevant because you will not implement it. Google _android network connection tutorial_ to learn more about working with Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Volley has different advantages such as request queue. Whereas in executor services it is quite difficult to queue requests. Volley need much less coding as compared to executor services. Remember that you will have a very hard time for queue requests in executor services.